# Count the continous occurence of characters in a string java 8

Tags: java-8

I am trying to write a method using Java 8 that takes two parameters, a string and an integer. The Method will return another string that is similar to the input string, but with certain characters removed.

It's going to remove characters from consecutive runs of the same character, where the length of the run is greater than the input parameter.

I can do this using simple Java for loop but I am looking for a solution using Java 8 features, may be lambda expressions.For example if the input to the method is ("aaab", 2) then it should return "aab" and if ("aabb", 1) it should return "ab".

Following is the code using for loop

```
     public String eliminate(String S, int allowed) {
         int count = 1;
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

         try {
             sb.append(S.charAt(0));
             for (int i = 1; i < S.length(); i++) {
                 if (S.charAt(i) == S.charAt(i - 1)) {
                     if (count < allowed) {
                         sb.append(S.charAt(i));
                         count = count + 1;
                     }
                 } else {
                     sb.append(S.charAt(i));
                     count = 1;
                 }
             }

         } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return sb.toString();
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That will help other members to understand your 

problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Streams aren’t really the best tool for this job. Streams are great when you can proces a lot of elements (like members of collection) in the same way independently. Ideally, processing each should be free from side effects. When you need to combine information from consecutive elements (which is necessary for counting runs of the same char), consider using a loop rather than a stream.

Comment: I was able to do that using simple for loops but is there any way I can do the same using Lambda expressions or the features that are new in Java 8. Actually I need to process lot of elements, I simplified the solution and posted here.

Comment: Yes, it can be done with streams. It’s complicated, I don’t want to bother doing it. The resulting code would not be nice code by any measure.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you want to use Java 8 features? I think that it will not be very elegant with streams, as streams only look at one element at a time. In order to keep the previous elements in mind you basically have to do the same stuff you are currently doing, as well. Other new features do not seem to be particularly useful either.

Instead, I think, a plain old regular expression is exactly what you need:

```
private static String eliminate(String input, int limit)
{
    return input == null ? null : input.replaceAll("(.)(\\1{" + (limit - 1) + "})\\1*", "$1$2");
}
```

This method shortens each sequencs of repeating chars to the specified length. The replace works like this:

- Find a substring that has

  - `(.)` one character (use something else instead of '.' like \w for specific chars)
  - `(\\1{" + (limit - 1) + "})` followed by (limit-1) of the same char
  - `\\1*` followed by any number of that same char
- and replace it with

  - `$1` the first part (one char) and
  - `$2` the second part (limit-1 chars)